# React-native Run-ios build failed .error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have seen some similar questions. But none of them solved my problems.
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.4
Simulator Version 10.1 (SimulatorApp-877 CoreSimulator-587.35) 
Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)

After upgrading the xcode to 10.2 this problem started
The following build commands failed:
        CompileXIB /Users/rezwanakabita/Desktop/Navigation_Practice/react-native-firebase-starter/ios/RNFirebaseStarter/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
(1 failure)

I tried all the solutions in StackOverflow Previous questions. But none solved my problem. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

```
{
  "name": "RNFirebaseStarter",
  "version": "5.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone X\"",
    "apk": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.0",
    "realm": "^2.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary fix mentioned in react-native github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24450) is to use `Legacy Build System`

`File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System -> Legacy Build System`